# Safe to puppet add system users to Debian

Tags: debian, puppet

I would like to add via puppet a system user to Debian boxes.

The user is:

```
user { 'puppet':
  ensure  => 'present',
  comment => 'puppetserver daemon',
  gid     => '109',
  groups  => ['www-data'],
  home    => '/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver',
  shell   => '/bin/false',
  uid     => '107',
}
```

(uid and gid taken from user created by the package `puppetserver`).

Can I be confident uid 107 is not already taken on some boxes by other services? Are there `safe uid`s on Debian? How does it work the system users' uid allocation in Debian?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you google for "Debian user id" you will find the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.2.2) which describes different ranges in the uid space.

UIDs 100-999 are used for packages, so collisions are possible and you should not use that. Instead put your site-local schema into the 1000-59999 range. I would also suggest not to start at 1000 and use 1007, because some system may have eight "real" user accounts. Start your own range of Puppet-generated and managed uids at some high number, e.g. at 50000.